# How to import specific data from a txt file

Tags: octave

I have around 2000 txt files following the same structure containing summarized information from different weather stations. I would like to create a matrix extracting some specific fields from them,  one column with the name of the file, another with the coordinates and another with  the values at the lower part of the file (they are yearly mean values of different stuff).

Here is attached a screenshot of one of them. I’ve imported to excel and found out that they can be imported as tab delimited files but that’s just nice to know information. The txt files are the monthly mean data from the yearly-by-minute data on the CVS files that they are on screen.

I took a Matlab /Octave class but we never really cover working with external files other than matrix files. I would appreciate some help with the subject. 
Thanks.

Here is one of the files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f6guokeybgxs9d9/MX_0010-mon.txt?dl=0

[image]

Comment: A screenshot of your data... If there would be just a better way

Comment: And I'm pretty sure you could provide a link to that data and the used format isn't arbitrary but has a name

Comment: yeah, i didn't put a lot of thought on that, I just uploaded a link